# Transparency in beamer if not uncovered in order

Tags: beamer, pause, transparent

I want to show the entire slide transparent until it is properly uncovered. But I do not uncover them necessarily in the order in which they are written (parts of formulae are shown later). I have switched from `\onslide` and `\pause` to  `\uncover<1-+(-2),+->{}` as advised previously. But this does not work in the example below, specifically for `\onslide<5->{xx}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=10}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Signals}\uncover<1-+(-2),+->{}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Informed investment banks receive an imperfect signal \textcolor<2-3>{red}{s} on the \textcolor<2-3>{blue}{return}:
    \item $\textcolor<3,6>{blue}{R}=\alert<3-4,6>{s}\onslide<5->{+\textcolor<5-6>{green}{\varepsilon}}$
    \item For uninformed investment banks it is $\textcolor<4>{red}{E\left[s\right]=\mu}$, $\textcolor<4,6>{red}{Var\left[s\right]=\sigma_S^2}$
    \item $\textcolor<5>{green}{E\left[\varepsilon\right]=0}$, $\textcolor<5,6>{green}{Var\left[\varepsilon\right]=\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2}$
    \item $\textcolor<6>{blue}{Var\left[R\right]}=\textcolor<6>{blue}{\sigma_R^2}=\textcolor<6>{red}{\sigma_S^2}+\textcolor<6>{green}{\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2}$\onslide<7>{}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\onslide<1-2,5->{...}` to avoid the double transparency on the first two overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=10}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Signals}\uncover<1-+(-2),+->{}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Informed investment banks receive an imperfect signal \textcolor<2-3>{red}{s} on the \textcolor<2-3>{blue}{return}:
    \item $\textcolor<3,6>{blue}{R}=\alert<3-4,6>{s}\onslide<1-2,5->{+\textcolor<5-6>{green}{\varepsilon}}$
    \item For uninformed investment banks it is $\textcolor<4>{red}{E\left[s\right]=\mu}$, $\textcolor<4,6>{red}{Var\left[s\right]=\sigma_S^2}$
    \item $\textcolor<5>{green}{E\left[\varepsilon\right]=0}$, $\textcolor<5,6>{green}{Var\left[\varepsilon\right]=\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2}$
    \item $\textcolor<6>{blue}{Var\left[R\right]}=\textcolor<6>{blue}{\sigma_R^2}=\textcolor<6>{red}{\sigma_S^2}+\textcolor<6>{green}{\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2}$\onslide<7>{}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]